# how to sum of all user orders in typeorm

Tags: node.js-typeorm

> const query = getManager()
> .createQueryBuilder(Users, 'user')
> .addSelect("SUM(user.orders)", "totalOrders")
> .groupBy("user.id");
>
> this code is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
    const query = getManager()
        .createQueryBuilder(Users, 'user')
        .where('user.userType = :userType', { userType: 'user' })
        .loadRelationCountAndMap("user.totalorders", "user.orders")
        .groupBy("user.id");


note:-
   user.totalOrders=this is aliases
   user.orders=this is Table colum name
```